# Rotate iText7 XObject prior to placing on canvas

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I am looking to copy an existing PDF and Paste on top of another existing PDF.

I am following the sample show [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/clone-superimposing-content-one-pdf-another-pdf). There doesn't seem function to rotate an XObject.  Would the only way to do this be to duplicate the srcDoc, rotate, save, then copy the rotated document as an XObject and paste into the canvas?

Comment: As a followup, I have a document that is displayed in landscape orientation.  So, the page has a rotation property of 90 applied to it.  I would like to actually create a new document that is Letter landscape, so a page with a rectangle of 792, 612. Then copy the content from the orginal pdf and paste it into the new one with the proper orientation.  I have looked at the "Page orientation and rotation" sample on itext page as well as "How to fix the orientation of a PDF page in order to scale it?" which showed how to scale, but ignored the rotation question. This seems like it should be easy.

Comment: The question is odd because of the words *prior to*. You should define the rotation when adding the XObject to the canvas. Currently you use `canvas.addXObject(page, 0, 0);` which doesn't involve any rotation. You should use the [`addXObject()`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/canvas/PdfCanvas.html#addXObject-com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.xobject.PdfXObject-float-float-float-float-float-float-) method that allows you to define a rotation. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30498670/1622493) if you aren't familiar with the parameters.

Comment: Thank you. The link clears up the confusion I had.